# How do I update a 2nd hand bought Juniper SRX240

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx

I bought a used SRX240 on ebay to learn a bit about it (and use it as a home router).
Upon starting it seems it has a very old firmware, so I wanted to update it.
So I created an account on juniper.com, but when I try to access the firmware under https://webdownload.juniper.net/swdl/dl/secure/site/1/record/65481.html I get the error: "You have encountered this error because your account privileges do not permit access to the information or service requested."

What do I need to do or rather - what is the best/easiest way to get the upgrade?

Comment: Difficult decision, Diogo gave the background (marked as answered), Viktor the practical workaround (up'ed by one). It's not really what I had hoped for especially as this means I am behind in terms of security updates :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need an active support contract in order to be able to download firmwares/software from the Juniper website. The error message you are seeing is expected if you haven't associated any support contract with the SRX serial number.

HTH